# <jsp:useBean> has body whose execution is conditional but in this case its getting executed everytime, why?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

This is my jsp in which i have written **useBean** standard action and that contains a body of **jsp:setProperty** too!!
According to the rules the body of useBean tag should be executed only when Container is making a new Bean because of useBean tag, if Bean does not exist.

But in my case, i have already made Person.class bean in foo folder in classes folder of web-inf.
So rule says that if Bean already exist then setProperty tag should not be executed but it is getting executed everytime.

And if i removes the Bean from the foo folder then i gets a Exception of **NoClassDefFound**

Please provide the proper reasoning or give me any logic for this, if some one knows about it.

**action.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="foo.Person"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Action JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Standard Actions are used Here.</h1>
<br>
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Person" scope="request" >
<jsp:setProperty name="person" property="name" value="Ankur Garg" />
</jsp:useBean>
Name is: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" />
<br>
Name set by Standard action: 

<% 
foo.Person p = (foo.Person) pageContext.getAttribute("person",PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
%>

<%=
p.getName()
%>

<br>

Residence not set:
<%=
p.getResidence()
%>

Password passes by user is: 
<%
    String param = request.getParameter("Password");
    out.print("<br>"+param);
%>

<br>
<a href="CallActionJsp">Call Again </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks & Regards 
Ankur Garg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *According to the rules the body of `useBean` tag should be executed only when Container is making a `new Bean` because of useBean tag, if `Bean` does not exist.*
>
> *But in my case, i have already made `Person.class` bean in `foo` folder in `classes` folder of `web-inf`. So rule says that if `Bean` already exist then `setProperty` tag should not be executed but it is getting executed everytime.*

You're confusing "classes" with "instances". The `Person.class` does not count as a bean instance. It's the blueprint of the bean class.

The part *"if `Bean` does not exist"* concerns the instance of the bean class which is been placed in the specified scope. You've specified it to be placed in the request scope. So every single HTTP request will recreate the bean instance simply because the instance will be trashed by end of request. If you place it in the session scope by `scope="session"` then it will be created on start of HTTP session and be trashed on end of session. A session can span multiple requests.

Comment: Yeah i got it now, actually in book it was return that if bean doesn't exist that's why i interpreted it wrong, it should be return like "bean instance" As you mentioned, any way thanks for your clarification, i am obliged.
Thanku very much!!!